# libcurl HTTP POST doesn't work

Tags: c++, http, libcurl

I'm trying to send HTTPS POST request using libcurl.
Here's the code:

```
CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
if (!curl) return "";

CURLcode res;
std::string request = "https://some-site.com/test.php";
std::string response;

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, request);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "email=test&pass=test");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

And here's the WriteCallback:

```
size_t WriteCallback(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t count, void* stream)
{
    ((std::string*)stream)->append((char*)ptr, 0, size * count);
    return size * count;
}
```

When I send a request, the fields are filling successfully, but the form is not sending. I'm not redirecting to another page.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the return code of `curl_easy_perform`? Any logs?

Comment: Return code is 0.

Comment: CURLOPT_VERBOSE log: https://pastebin.com/TaPApAz4

Comment: `CURLOPT_URL` expects a `char*` pointer, but you are passing it a `std::string` instead.  You need to change this: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, request);` to this instead: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, request.c_str());`

Comment: The `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` log clearly shows the `POST` request is succeeding, the server is sending back a `200 OK` response with 5286 bytes of HTML data. What does that HTML actually say? The response does not have an HTTP redirect to another URL. Does the HTML include a client-side script that redirects to another URL? If you are expecting an HTTP redirect and not getting one, then you need to debug your PHP code. On the other hand, the log shows 32 bytes being posted, but you are giving `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` only 20 bytes, so where is the extra 12 bytes coming from?